Minimum representation of polyhedron
I have a question related to polyhedron theory. It is well known that if a polyhedron has $f$ many facets then we need at least $f$ many inequalities to define it(here I mean linear inequalities). Also if the polyhedron is full dimensional then this bound is tight.
My question is what happens if the polyhedron is lower dimensional. So let's say in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have a polyhedron that is $k<n$ dimensional with $f$ many facets. From the previous results we can obviously define it with $f+2(n-k)$ inequalities ($f$ many for the facets and $2(n-k)$ to define the affine hull). However this is just an upper bound since for instance we can define a point with just $3$ inequalities in the plane, we do not need $4$.
So my question is: Is there a tight bound on how many are required in this case?

Maybe $f+n-k+1$? The idea is that, where you're constraining the extra $n-k$ dimensions with a (degenerate) rectangular box, you could constrain them with a simplex instead.

I think the answer should be that $f+n-k+1$. You can always do it with that many since $x_1=...=x_{n-k}=0$ can be modeled by them being non-negative and their sum being non-positive. But the question is why can't we do with less?
